# User.Identity.Name is null everytime with MongoDB Token Based auth

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I created project using Asp.Net Core 2.1 Web API (MongoDB) and used token based authentication. User.Identity.Name is getting null. Also User.Claims is showing "Enumeration yielded no results".

```
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(config.Value.Secret);
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
    {
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, UserDtos.Id.ToString()),
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Id),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, user.Id),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
    }),
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
};
var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
UserDtos.Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

Comment: Are you using the correct scheme in your webapi? Do you have Jwt and Cookie authentication in the same app? If so you have make one of them default and the other one name explicitly in the `[Authorize(Scheme = "...")]` attribute

Comment: You show how you generate the token but how are you *using* the token? I assume that you have verified that the token contains the information you need (e.g. using jwt.io). So that means that something is wrong with how the token is consumed. What does your authentication setup look like with ASP.NET Core? Have you set up the JWT Bearer authentication properly?

Comment: @Tseng, i used token based authentication only and its working fine too. Problem is i am not getting User.Identity.Name value in  web api controller